# Angular: Image of a page searched in Google indicates the title of the main page

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, seo

I developed an App with Angular Universal. Everything works very well, the meta, json ld application too. But I discovered a problem with the url of my website page images which is found in Google search results.
For example, when I search for the title of an article in Google Image, the result indicates the title of the home page not of single page, and when I click on the title or image it takes me to the home page and not to the sngle page I am looking for.
Do you have any ideas ?
Thank you.